# Nivo slider stops in second slider on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, opencart, nivo-slider

This is the site: http://hugsforkids.com.au/
The homepage slider occasionally stops in the second slider. This doesn't happen every time, but it happens quiet often. 
The slider works on firefox, safari. Just has issue on Chrome. This is very wield, there is no js error.

Does anyone know what's going on with this slider and chrome?

Site was made by opencart 1.5.1, it is a sefault Nivo slider.

Many Thanks

Comment: Sometimes, it stops in the 3rd slide.

Answer (score 0):

Never faced this kind of problem before.
May be you can try this

http://doctype.com/does-my-nivo-slideshow-transition-stop-working-after-second-slide

Comment: Thank you for your help. on the link, it says:

"Have you tried increasing the pauseTime, or reducing the animSpeed so that they are not the same value? It looks like the image is changing before the transition has time to finish"

No, I didn't change the pauseTime and animSpeed at all.